# Get Current Page Information immediately after authorization when app is installed as a tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My facebook application is installed on multiple pages as a tab. 
When a user clicks on the tab link from a page, if the user has not authorized my app,  I redirect the user for authorization.

After authorization, the user is redirected to my site with the "code" value. Now, at this point, I can get the "access token" for this user but I do not have the current page id.

I need the current page id in order to show the page specific data to this user.

However, after the user has authorized my user, when the user comes back later, i get the page information from the signed request. But I also need the page information immediately after authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your app first loaded as a tab, you can read the "[signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)" and compose the redirect_uri with it.

```
var encodeURI = encodeURIComponent("http://myapp.com?pageid=123");
```

and redirect your user to somewhere like

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=encodeURI&response_type=token
```